# Strange requests to /.well-known/ URL with Referrer "binance.com"

Tags: logging, server

I have a website that has nothing to do with Crypto, however, for the last week(s) I have seen strange requests coming from "binance.com" that try to access /.well-known path, which returns a 301 (I have fixed the 301 issue, now it should return 404).

```
Line 88: 172.70.110.97 - - [03/Nov/2022:12:18:40 +0000] "GET /.well-known/ HTTP/1.1" 301 246 "binance.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36"
Line 89: 172.70.110.31 - - [03/Nov/2022:12:18:41 +0000] "GET /.well-known HTTP/1.1" 301 247 "binance.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36"
Line 90: 172.70.110.75 - - [03/Nov/2022:12:18:41 +0000] "GET /.well-known/ HTTP/1.1" 301 246 "binance.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36"
Line 91: 172.70.111.67 - - [03/Nov/2022:12:18:41 +0000] "GET /.well-known HTTP/1.1" 301 247 "binance.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36"
Line 92: 172.70.110.97 - - [03/Nov/2022:12:18:41 +0000] "GET /.well-known/ HTTP/1.1" 301 246 "binance.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36"
```

Can someone explain this to me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I also see a lot of traffic to my websites with a referrer domain of `binance.com`, as have many others.

If you check the IP address, you'll probably see their owned by a VPN provider, so they're probably not *actually* originating from Binance. But why then would someone who wants to be anonymous identify themselves as `binance.com`?

We can only speculate as to why, but one plausable explanation is that a malicious actor (could be a binance competitor, disgruntled customer, ex-employee, etc) is crawling the internet, doing strange/malicious-looking things, and pretending to be Binance in order to defame/demote Binance's SEO rankings or to put Binance on an RBL.

For more information, see [this hackernews thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=31107431)

- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=31107431